# Splitting and combining of Double in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, math, time

I want to store duration of time in a `Double` and need to extract high and low values of `Double` (hour and minute) for accessing them. I also need to be able to set `Double` with two `Ints` (`hour` and `minute`).
And I got something here now:

```
extension Double {
    func hour() -> Int {
        return NSNumber(double: floor(self)).integerValue
    }

    func minute() -> Int {
        return NSNumber(float: Float(Double((self - floor(self)) * 100))).integerValue
    }

    init(hour: Int, minute: Int) {
        self = Double(hour) + ( Double(minute) / 100 )
    }
}
```

And then I've performed some testing with this in my appDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
var time: Double = 18.30

NSLog("Time is \"%f\" - so hours is \"%d\" and minutes is \"%d\".", time, time.hour(), time.minute())

time = Double(hour: 10, minute: 1)
NSLog("Time is \"%f\" - so hours is \"%d\" and minutes is \"%d\".", time, time.hour(), time.minute())

time = Double(hour: 15, minute: 45)
NSLog("Time is \"%f\" - so hours is \"%d\" and minutes is \"%d\".", time, time.hour(), time.minute())
```

Now, this code works. One might wonder why I convert `Double` to `Float` in the `minute()` function. This is because of an unknown issue that I faced when using `Double`s without converting them to `Float`s before converting these `Float`s to `Int`s. If minutes didn't end with `0`, one minute was  subtracted for unknown reasons.
For example, *10:42* returned *10 hours* and *41 minutes*.
 But *10:30* was still *10 hours* and *30 minutes*.
Also *10:00* was *10 hours* and *0 minutes*.

This routine that I posted here seems to be working, but I was just wondering, if I am as efficient as possible... There's more conversion here than what would be needed.
So, any improvements?

And does someone know the reason for unknown issue with decremented minute I mentioned?

Comment: So your hour has 100 minutes ?

Comment: Usually we store a duration as a number of seconds (i.e. `hour * 60 * 60 + minute * 60`).  The standard libraries support this and you can do arithmetic on durations if you store them this way.  Why do you want to store a duration as `hour + minute / 100`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *binary* floating point number such as `Double` or `Float` cannot represent the number `10.42` exactly, therefore 
multiplying the fractional part by 100 and truncating the result might give `41`.
With the conversion to `Float` you are just "hiding" the problem.

Here is a version that *rounds*  instead of truncating, and is overall a bit simpler. I have adopted the notation of "minute" from your code,
even if it represents 1/100 of an hour and not 1/60.

```
extension Double {

    func hour() -> Int {
        return Int(self)
    }

    func minute() -> Int {
        return Int(round(self * 100.0)) % 100
    }

    init(hour: Int, minute: Int) {
        self = Double(hour) + ( Double(minute) / 100 )
    }
}
```

Other possible approaches to solve your problem:

- Store the duration as an *integer* representing the total
  number of minutes. E.g. "10:42" would be stored as `10*60 + 42`.
  Then you have no rounding problems at all.
- Use the Foundation
  type `NSDecimalNumber` instead of `Double`, which can represent
  a decimal integer with up to 38 digits exactly.

Comment: I wanted to use a picker with 2 components that can be used to enter duration - that's where this extension of Double can make things real simple.. I could also use a type of my own, or nsdate or many other approaches, but this seemed to me like a most simple solution.. Fraction.

Comment: @jake1981: Well, it's up to you. I have tried to explain the rounding problem, suggested some workaround and an alternative. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Yes - well, it's just a container that is supposed to be as universal as possible - I think I might be able to re-use my code on another projects, so that's why I chose this way to store the data - it's not a problem at all that "my hour" has 100 minutes, as calculation isn't supposed to happen here, it's just that I want my picker view to return value some how - I could make my own type, use array, dictionary, etc.. But this seemed like a best way to do it - might not be actually the best way, but I'll take this approach, and your alternative.. Works just perfectly. Thank you.